# POM dependency still shows old class file

Tags: maven, compilation, intellij-idea, pom.xml

This is on IntellijIdea  v12 Ultimate.

1. I changed a Java class on a dependant project,
2. 'install'ed it     correctly to my local Maven repository
3. Changed the POM file of the  original project correctly to map to the Snapshot version of the
   local jar from M2 repo.
4. Did a clean and compile, which  succeeded.

   However, when I go to the existing class file, it still shows compilation errors. I understand Maven compilation and the idea compilation must be different. So, the question is, how to refresh the compilational units. Oh and I also tried, changing the compiler to Eclipse from Project Structure, to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have set IntelliJ to auto refresh the Maven model, it will still be using the classpath of the old model it initially parsed.

Find the Maven snap-in/sidebar/whatever-you-call-it and click the refresh button *in that pane* (as distinct from the refresh changed files button on the main toolbar or the refresh changed files button on the SCM snap-in/sidebar/whatever-you-call-it or the ...)

[image: The Maven snap-in with the refresh button to click]

## Update

Added picture of the pane with the refresh button to click.

Did you open the project as a Maven project?

Are you putting the `.java` files in the correct directory structure that Maven thinks should be used (because if they are in the wrong directories, Maven will just not compile them and hence will not see any errors in the files)

Comment: Nope, this didn't work.But then,even before, the Maven compile goal goes through successfully, its the Java class which shows those tiny red marks, if you know what i mean!